# Validation.ErrorTemplate only visible when at least once no error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have two DateTimePickers from Xceed WPF Toolkit and use [MahApps Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro), the validation error template is the [default one provided by Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/ValidationErrorTemplate.xaml) (`{DynamicResource ValidationErrorTemplate}`). The validation is handled with validation attributes like this:

```
[TimeSpanValidator]
public TimeSpan StartTime
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}

[TimeSpanValidator]
public TimeSpan EndTime
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

The referenced validator class:

```
public class TimeSpanValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        EditEntryViewModel viewmodel = validationContext.ObjectInstance as EditEntryViewModel;
        if (viewmodel == null)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Error in validation: ViewModel was not assigned.");
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        if (!viewmodel.ValidTimeSpan)
            return new ValidationResult("End time must not be earlier than start time.");
        if (!viewmodel.TimeSpanUnoccupied)
            return new ValidationResult("The timespan overlaps with an existing entry.");
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as I don't have an error when opening the window. But when I already have one (in my case, the prefilled times create a timespan that overlaps with an existing one) the error template isn't shown at all, even when I change the value to another invalid one, until it was at least once a valid input.

I stepped through the validator with the debugger, it always returns an invalid result when there is an error. Also I can't close the dialog when the values are invalid, the `ValidTimeSpan` and `TimeSpanUnoccupied` are working correctly. So it's really only the displaying of the error template that goes wrong. And I have no clue why.

Also this only occurs with the error template. When I bind a tooltip on the `Validation.HasError` it shows the tooltip like intended, even when the error already exists when the window opens:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem actually is. That said...

I have run into similar problems myself. In particular, it appears that validation occurs *only* when the target property changes and is copied back to the source. This doesn't happen when the control is first initialized, and so the validation step doesn't occur.

I have found that a work-around for this particular issue is to force the validation to occur by calling the [`BindingExpression.UpdateSource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource(v=vs.110).aspx) method after the control is loaded. I.e. add a handler for the [`Loaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event and call the method there. For example:

```
private void textBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

If the above does not in fact address your problem, please improve your question by providing a good MCVE that reliably reproduces the problem. Alternatively, look at the question here: [Initial validation on dynamically added control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/408353). In that question, validation itself isn't the problem, but rather updating the adorner that provides user feedback regarding the failed validation. There's not enough information in your question at the moment for me to be able to tell where exactly the problem may lie, but hopefully one or the other of these answers will help.